# Market train, market destination

Tags: meaning

In a text I'm translating, I've come across the concept of a market train. To my misinformed understanding, market trains might be those trains that carry crates and boxes for commercial purposes, but this doesn't seem to be the case (despite the train having a freight engine).

Rather, the carriages (we're talking a WW2 era train here) are meant to transport a large number of people from the main town to a satellite town which is called a "market destination" - a place where everybody in town has an aunt or a cousin.

What does "market" mean in this context? How else can I call this kind of train?

---

The text comes from an obscure roleplaying game manual published this century and inspired by a book by Alan Furst called *The Polish Officer*. The game is set in Poland around the day when the Germans invaded Warsaw.

I see in comments about market-day trains and to be true there's this passage in the manual:

> They are market coaches for carrying people out of the city on Sundays and holidays

and:

> [It] will look like an innocent market train, the sort that putters between cities on week-ends making every stop on the line.

Comment: Is this a 'market-day' train?  Does it only run on the days when the satellite town has a market?

Comment: It's a [***goods train***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/goods_train), not a "market train".

Comment: "Market train" is not a UK term that I recognise, but "goods train" is, as @FumbleFingers has pointed out.

Comment: Sometimes people mistake an adjective plus a noun for an "existing thing" when, in fact, it is the writer writing. If these trains took people to a particular market, then calling it a "market train" in justifiable. If, today, there was a train used to shuttle people to a destination for a particular event, and I were a journalist, I might, in my article, refer to that specially scheduled train as "the event train" for my specific purposes. An event train is not a type of train, but it could be well be a train in my article about some event. Cheers.

Comment: Can you please provide more context? What is the text that you are translating? What country and date? Could we have some example sentences?

Comment: There will be plenty of Victorian references to "market trains" taking people from rural areas to the "market towns", but since [the Beeching cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beeching_cuts) the concept (and the collocation) don't really have any currency.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I daresay, but it's not a term I've ever heard. All trains had to carry goods (of any description). It was a legal requirement. So, why the need for "market trains"? Milk trains (early morning), yes. I've ridden those.

Comment: @Mick: I used to work in the UK bus industry, where some companies still run "market buses". They've usually got surplus buses (and drivers) in between the morning & evening peak periods, so they can run the off-peak buses on the cheap (allowing poorer people in rural areas to get to town for a realistic price & travel time). Before Beeching we had a lot more railway tracks serving smaller population centres, so trains would have been used in the same way.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so market as in economical, cheap? Why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: Alan Furst is a much overlooked spy thriller writer. He is American originally. I recommend all his books.

Comment: @Zachiel: I didn't mean to imply that "market" means "cheap". I've never come across the concept of "market coaches" per your first example, but [this Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22market+trains%22+%22Sundays+and+holidays%22) suggests it's a misuse anyway (those examples all say the market trains *don't* run on Sundays and holidays). But if we assume the actual rolling stock really was "spare" at weekends, they could have perhaps used them to run cheap "peasants' day out" trips. It's not part of modern English usage, though.

Comment: Why are you assuming BrE usage?

Comment: @FumbleFingers From another (reliable) UK contact: "Used in the flower industry to get fresh blooms from the growers to the major distributions centres around the UK - or so I understood from my Grandfather and his family who were in that industry."

Comment: @Mick: The point is that "market train" isn't an established collocation with a fixed meaning - we've already unearthed various historical usages where it means different things (trains taking shoppers to market, trains taking *goods* to market, such trains being used when "spare" to take city-dwellers out on day-trips, "commercial" trains carrying civilians rather than the military, etc.). So the question boils down to a fairly pointless "what does this mean *in context?*" - not helped by being presented using *different* examples in different contexts.

Comment: The action is Furst novels occurs mostly in France and Middle European countries. Not the UK.

Comment: @Lambie the action happens in Poland, but is this really important? I mean, maybe "market train" is how people in Poland would call it, maybe it's how Furst would call it in his own language.

Comment: @Zachiel It might have a meaning in the context of WWII which we do not know and one that is given by the Polish. I have already provided my explanation. Not every expression like market train is necessarily an existing expression. Thank goodness for that or literary writing would be impossible. Everything would already be "out there".

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is explained in a 1876 [House of Commons document](https://books.google.com/books?id=dixcAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA13&dq=%22market%20train%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTnKTc6M7RAhWr54MKHaAkB0g4ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=%22market%20train%22&f=false):

Mr. Samuda testifying 4 April 1876:

> I think it is perfectly clear that a market train, that is to say, a train running only on a Saturday, perhaps once a month or once a fortnight, was not within the exemption.

See also the 23 June 1917 article [Market Train Service](https://books.google.com/books?id=8-BFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA1055&dq=%22market%20train%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqgb3p7s7RAhUF94MKHYrJBlk4ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=%22market%20train%22&f=false) in The Country Gentleman, Vol. 82.:

> "I live sixty miles from a city market, and although I would like to ship my fat calves, sheep, pork products and other surplus farm produce to the town trade, the transportation charges on small shipments and the slow..." ...
>
> To cater to the needs of just such small operators a few of the leading railroads have operated special market trains, either daily or once weekly, through a territory which extends from seventy-five to one hundred miles along their route from a large city.  ...
>
> One road runs a market train once a week from a point sixty miles from the city

Comment: This may well be correct, but I think it is fair to say the term is scarcely ever used these days.

Comment: @TimLymington OP says "we're talking a WW2 era train here"